# How to use GET method in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to use GET method and Route it in Codeigniter?
I have this :

```
index.php?search_term=somestring
```

How to get the search term value in a controller and how to make the URL clean like the following one :

```
search/somestring
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation about routing? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html. It goes in to this quite in depth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract get variable from query string in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689629/how-to-extract-get-variable-from-query-string-in-codeigniter)

Comment: see also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694848/how-to-change-url-of-get-method-form-to-slashes-in-codeigniter-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this codes:

Html:

```
<?=form_open(base_url(), array('id' => 'search'))?>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword..." name="query" id="search_query">
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-search" type="button">
        Search
    </button>
<?=form_close()?>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#btn-search").click(function(){
    var query = $("#search_query").val();
    window.location = '/search/'+query;
});

$('form#search').bind("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var query = $("#search_query").val();
        return window.location = '/search/'+query;
    }
});
```

Route:

```
$route['search/(:any)'] = 'Controller/search/$1';
```

Controller:

```
public function search($keyword = null)
{
    if($keyword == null)
        redirect(base_url());
    else
    {
        $keyword = urldecode($keyword);
        $data = array(
            'category' => $this->Category_Model->search($keyword)
        );
        $this->load->view('search', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use get method and get url data 
like this `$this->input->get();`

If you want to make the URL clean so you should route your url

go to

> application/config/routes.php

```
$route['search/(:any)'] = "controller/function/$1";
```

You can get url segment in controller use this `$this->uri->segment(2);`